# Logging snmpbulkwalk

Tags: logging, snmp, net-snmp

I am trying to log the command for `snmpbulkwalk` using

```
snmpbulkwalk -Lf /etc/snmp/snmplog -v 2c -c public 192.168.2.4 1.3.6.1.4.9
```

I can see that the file `/etc/snmp/snmplog` is being overwritten, however it is blank and the result of the bulkwalk is just displayed on the terminal. Anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: Sorry, it's not clear to me that this question belongs on StackOverflow as it doesn't seem related to programming. Perhaps try on ServerFault.com instead, which deals with server administration?

Answer (score 1):

Look at man page for snmpcmd. The -L is for logging problems (e.g. host not reachable) not for redirecting the output of the netsnmp commands.

Quoting snmpcmd man page:

> **NAME**
>          snmpcmd - options and behaviour common to most of the Net-SNMP command-line tools
>
> // SNIP
>
> **LOGGING OPTIONS**  The mechanism and destination to use for logging of warning and error messages can be controlled by passing various parameters to the -L flag.
>
> // SNIP
>
> **OUTPUT OPTIONS**
>          The format of the output from SNMP commands can be controlled using various parameters of the -O flag.  The effects of these
>   sub-options can be seen by comparison with the following default
>   output (unless otherwise specified):
>
> // SNIP